# AngularJs filter by inverval date

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to filter the news that I retrieve from a rss to show only the ones published in an interval of time/date.

In my html view I alredy have got the item field

```
publishedDate":"Mon, 31 Mar 2014 12:57:58 -0700"
```

and the interval time, for example 24h or in secs or whatever in $scope.timeinterval.

```
<li ng-repeat="feed in feeds | filter:XXXXX">
```

So, how could I put the comparison between both intervals? Show I do it in the controller? If so, return what to the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter logic is too specific to your requirements. The best way is to have a custom filter that takes the form of an expression - a function in this case.

Thus, the custom filter function takes a single record as parameter. The function should return `true` or `false` depending on whether the passed record should be shown in the view or not.

Thus, this would look like:

```
$scope.customFilter = function (singleRecord) {
    //singleRecord is one record of the repeat directive
    //Here, you add your custom filter logic.

    //Return true if the record should be shown else false
};
```

Your view will then use this record as:

```
<li ng-repeat="feed in feeds | filter:customFilter()"></li>
```

Comment: Thank you! Where should go the customFilter? It looks like inside the controller but I thought there was a filter.js file for that.

Comment: It goes inside the controller for the view. However, if you wish to have a separate dedicated filter.js file, then you need to use the `app.filter` function to create one - see [this](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) step in the AngularJS tutorial

Comment: Perfect. I found one problem, I have to pass feed.publishedDate to the controller, but filter:customFilter(feed,feed.publishedDate) does't work, how should I do that?

Comment: Eh? You are getting `feed` - can't your read `publishedDate` from it? Why do you need a separate parameter?